# I'm looking for a book where a family go camping in the woods and aliens start attacking

Tags: story-identification, novel, books, aliens, young-adult

So the book starts off with the family deciding to take a trip to a cabin in the woods. The daughter also has her best friend with her.

The points I remember from the book:

- The father has an affair with the daughter's friend
- At night, the aliens come, they look like giant flying insects like bees with abdomens that glow different colours
- They manage to get a hold of the dad while he's fighting them off and he later returns zombie-like and talking for the aliens
- The aliens eventually get fought off one by one (I think)

I read this book in the early 2000s but it may even have been around way before then as I found it at a second hand book store.